# Is $\{\varnothing\}\in\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $\{\varnothing\}\in\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ true?

Can we use the same explanation as in $\{\varnothing\}\subseteq\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$? That is, $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ has two elements $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$. The right set $\{\varnothing\}$ is its subset because it contains only one of them. Therefore, true.

With the only difference being that we replace the word subset and instead say that the right set $\{\varnothing\}$ is an element of $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$, therefore true?

Can we say the same thing for $\{\varnothing\}\in\{\varnothing,\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$, and $\{\{\varnothing\}\}\in\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$?

Comment: I'm wondering if we can invoke the axiom of powerset to answer this question in a more generalized manner? {∅, {∅}} is ℘({∅}) and therefore {∅} ∈ {∅, {∅}} is true. Similarly, {∅, {{∅}}} ≠ ℘({∅}) and {∅, {∅}} ≠ ℘({{∅}})? I am not well versed with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Axiomatic_set_theory to know if a proof through this route exists.

Comment: For my own sanity-- er, understanding, ∅ means the empty set, right? i.e. it's equivalent to $\{ \}$. $\{∅\}$ is a set with one element, which is the empty set?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes That's correct.

Answer (score 43):

> Is {∅} ∈ {∅, {∅}} true?

**YES**.

---

> Can we use the same explanation as in {∅} ⊆ {∅, {∅}}?

**NO**.

- You prove that $$\{\emptyset\}\in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$$ by proving that $\{\emptyset\}$ is **an element of** $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$. This is fairly obvious, and is the same as proving that $0$ is an element of $\{0,1\}$.
- You prove that $$\{\emptyset\}\subseteq \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$$ by showing that **every element of** $\{\emptyset\}$ is also an element of $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$. Since $\{\emptyset\}$ has only one element, $\emptyset$, this means you need to prove that $\emptyset$ is an element of $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.

---

> Can we say the same thing for {∅} ∈ {∅, {{∅}}}, and {{∅}} ∈ {∅, {∅}}?

**NO**.

Remember:

> $A$ is a subset of $B$ (denoted as $A\subseteq B$) if and only if for every $a\in A$, it is true that $a\in B$.

This means that:

- $\{\emptyset\}\in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ is true the same way $1\in \{0,1\}$ is true.
- $\{\emptyset\} \subset \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ is true the same way $\{a\}\subset \{a,b\}$ is true.
- $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \subset \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ is **true**, because every element of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ (there is only one) is an element of $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.
- $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ is **false**, because neither of the two elements in $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ is equal to $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to resolve some of your queries is by introducing convenient notation so as not to get lost in the curly braces, such as $0=\emptyset$, $1=\{\emptyset\}$, $2=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}=\{0,1\}$, etc. For example, the answer to your last question is negative because it is not true that $\{1\}\in\{0,1\}$, only that $\{1\}\subset\{0,1\}$.

Comment: That is incorrect: If you define 1={∅},the expression is 1∈{0,1} and not {1}∈{0,1}, which is true.

Comment: @Darkhogg I think the "last question" mentioned in this answer was $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\},$ which indeed is false and in which indeed $\{\{\emptyset\}\}=\{1\}$ according to the notation of this answer. I'm not convinced, however, that the extra notation is really going to help someone who isn't yet able to see that $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\not\in\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ in the original notation of the question.

Comment: That convenient notation may quickly become confusing too when you start asking if $1 \subseteq 2$ is true...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, obviously if you wish to study the set inclusion relations you have to restore some of the curly braces.  It remains true that *some* of the questions are more transparent using the abbreviated notation.